# An argument named "instance_type" is not expected here...amongst other unexpected arguments

Tags: module, arguments, terraform

I've got some code form a Udemy course and it's giving  the following errors. Can anybody point me in the right direction with this...it's probably really easy, but I'm really new to this to be honest.

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on lesson100.tf line 83, in module "ec2":
  83:   instance_type = "m4.large"

An argument named "instance_type" is not expected here.


Error: Unsupported argument

  on lesson100.tf line 85, in module "ec2":
  85:   subnet_id = element(data.aws_subnet_ids.all.ids, 0)

An argument named "subnet_id" is not expected here.


Error: Unsupported argument

  on lesson100.tf line 87, in module "ec2":
  87:   vpc_security_group_ids = ["${module.security_group.this_security_group_id}"]

An argument named "vpc_security_group_ids" is not expected here.


Error: Unsupported argument

  on lesson100.tf line 89, in module "ec2":
  89:   associate_public_ip_address = true

An argument named "associate_public_ip_address" is not expected here.
```

the full code is

```
provider "aws" {

  region = "eu-west-1"

}

##################################################################

# Data sources to get VPC, subnet, security group and AMI details

##################################################################

data "aws_vpc" "default" {

  default = true

}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "all" {

  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.default.id

}

data "aws_ami" "amazon_linux" {

  most_recent = true

  filter {

    name = "name"

    values = [

      "amzn-ami-hvm-*-x86_64-gp2",

    ]

  }

  filter {

    name = "owner-alias"

    values = [

      "amazon",

    ]

  }

}

module "security_group" {

  source = "terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws"

  name = "example"

  description = "Security group for example usage with EC2 instance"

  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.default.id

  ingress_cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  ingress_rules = ["http-80-tcp", "all-icmp"]

  egress_rules = ["all-all"]

}

module "ec2" {

  source = "../../"

  instance_count = 2

  name = "example-normal"

  ami = data.aws_ami.amazon_linux.id

  instance_type = "m4.large"

  subnet_id = element(data.aws_subnet_ids.all.ids, 0)

  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${module.security_group.this_security_group_id}"]

  associate_public_ip_address = true

}
```

Comment: Could it be due to the source being  source = "../../" ?

Comment: Your error is coming from a module you have locally but haven't shown the source for. Could you edit the question to include the module source as well please?

Answer (score 1):

make sure that your ec2 module 4 variables are matching the 4 arguments you are passing:

- `associate_public_ip_address`
- `vpc_security_group_ids`
- `subnet_id`
- `instance_type`

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me guys, I think that the module source is the problem here, I'll get onto the course vendor, I think they've missed a bit out